# updating ubuntu issue apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade, gpg, ppa

I am unable to update "sudo apt-get update" in my PC (Ubuntu 18.04). I keep receiving this error and tried many different solutions existed in StackExchange and Google, however, nothing seemed to work for this problem.

Could you please explain the issue I'm encountering and aid in solving it, thanks.

Here's the error and warning I'm encountering:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: FE85409EEAB40ECCB65740816AF0E1940624A220
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Did you read `man apt-secure`?

Comment: How (and why) did you install this ppa ? Last update of it was 2014. Get rid of it!

Comment: @pLumo, I didn't install as I recall,

Answer (score 2):

You may want to remove the ppa 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu trusty Release'  as trusty is no longer updated.

Try the following command to locate and remove the offending ppa

`sudo software-properties-gtk`

Comment: and it might also not work with OPs version of Ubuntu (=bionic).

Comment: perhaps you could the show the right command!!

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed

Comment: @pLumo, (sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa) what does he mean by "whatever" i'm not getting it

Comment: whatever is the name of the repository. You need `ppa:tualatrix/ppa`. If that does not work, read the third answer of that link

Comment: @pLumo, still not working.

Comment: please edit the question and update with the information what you tried and what happened then